# Adding App to Path on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, path, environment-variables

I'm in the process of migrating from Windows to Mac OS X. Right now, I'm trying to use [this plugin](https://github.com/mash/node-imagemagick-native) in an application. The plugin states:

```
Make sure you can find Magick++-config in your PATH.
```

My question is, how do I add that to my PATH on Mac OS X?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this plugin is only a binding for ImageMagick, but OS X does not come with ImageMagick. You can install it easily using Homebrew, MacPorts or Fink.

If you do have ImageMagick installed, you can add this line to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/ImageMagick
```